# How to get rainbow-delimiters/rainbow-blocks to highlight in-line math in LaTeX equations

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting

I'm using [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) with AUCTeX for LaTeX editing and would like to make [rainbow-delimiters](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters) and/or [rainbow-blocks](https://github.com/istib/rainbow-blocks) highlight LaTeX math equations. Unfortunately this only works partly, i.e., some equations get highlighted and some don't:

[image: Example: rainbow-delimiters]

In the example screenshot, in-line math enclosed in `$` does not get highlighted while the rest - including in-line math enclosed in `\(...\)` - does.

With `rainbow-blocks` it gets worse, as it will sometimes work in one place of the document and sometimes won't work regardless of scope.

[image: Example: rainbow-blocks]

**Q:** Does anyone know why this happens or how to get `rainbow-blocks` working for in-line math in LaTeX? Are there any working alternatives?

Comment: latex-mode in auctex seems to define "$" to have special syntax in the syntax-table, so perhaps font-lock's syntactic fontification is overriding any keyword-based fontification.

Comment: `highlight-parentheses` uses overlays instead of font lock, and it would be a very simple thing to use a temporary syntax-table for the duration of the overlay function.  https://github.com/nschum/highlight-parentheses.el  The function that would need to be altered in that library is `hl-paren-highlight`:  `(let ((my-syntax-table (make-syntax-table))) (with-syntax-table my-syntax-table . . .`  Unfortunately, that is another library than the one you have specified -- I do not know how to fix `rainbow-delimiters` -- perhaps you could open up an issue on Github with the maintainer.

Comment: Using `(with-silent-modifications (remove-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(face nil font-lock-face nil)) (add-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(face rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face)))` it is possible to replace the fontification within an embedded formula. But this does not work in an around advice of `rainbow-delimiters-propertize-delimiter`. This indicates that the fontification of `latex-mode` takes place after the fontification through `rainbow-delimiters-mode`.

Comment: rainbow-delimiters uses jit-lock directly. Maybe, syntactic fontification does not use jit-lock and we get a timing problem because of that?

Answer (score 2):

The following is more like a comment since

1. it solves only to a small part of the problem (`rainbow-delimiters-mode`)
2. it is not thoroughly tested (just with one latex-file)
3. I do not completely understand why it works (`font-lock-mode` is really quite a complicated machinery)

At first the solution for `rainbow-delimiters-mode`:

We replace the text property `font-lock-face` by `face` in `rainbow-delimiters-propertize-delimiter` and `rainbow-delimiters-unpropertize-delimiter`. Since `defsubst` is used in the package instead of `defun` we cannot employ `defalias` but must modify the functions themselves (as far as I understand it -- please comment if I am wrong in this regard).

The modified functions are:

```
(defsubst rainbow-delimiters-propertize-delimiter (loc depth)
  "Highlight a single delimiter at LOC according to DEPTH.

LOC is the location of the character to add text properties to.
DEPTH is the nested depth at LOC, which determines the face to use.

Sets text properties:
`font-lock-face' to the appropriate delimiter face.
`rear-nonsticky' to prevent color from bleeding into subsequent characters typed by the user."
  (with-silent-modifications
    (let ((delim-face (if (<= depth 0)
                          'rainbow-delimiters-unmatched-face
                        (rainbow-delimiters-depth-face depth))))
      ;; (when (eq depth -1) (message "Unmatched delimiter at char %s." loc))
      (add-text-properties loc (1+ loc)
               ;; 2015-05-24: Changed font-lock-face to face to enable rainbow after syntax fontification in latex-mode
               ;; (see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4260/how-to-get-rainbow-delimiters-rainbow-blocks-to-highlight-in-line-math-in-latex)
                           `(face ,delim-face
                             rear-nonsticky t)))))


(defsubst rainbow-delimiters-unpropertize-delimiter (loc)
  "Remove text properties set by rainbow-delimiters mode from char at LOC."
  (with-silent-modifications
    (remove-text-properties loc (1+ loc)
                ;; 2015-05-24: See corresponding line in `rainbow-delimiters-propertize-delimiter'.
                            '(face nil
                              rear-nonsticky nil))))
```

Now the reasoning:

The embedded formulas between the $-delimiters are syntax fontified by font-lock-mode (as already Kirill pointed out). The registration of this fontification looks normal (see variable `font-lock-syntactic-face-function` and function `font-latex-syntactic-face-function`).
But `describe-char` at the characters of an embedded formula shows that syntactic fontification uses the `face`-property instead of the `font-lock-face`-property.

The following is hypothetical since I do not completely understand the font-lock machinery which is quite complex.

It seems that `face` is stronger than `font-lock-face`.
Rainbow-delimiters uses `font-lock-face` which is dominated by `face` of syntactic fontification.
Nevertheless, we have the advantage that syntactic fontification comes first before search (keyword) based fontification which in turn uses jit-lock (see info-pages of `font-lock-mode`).

That leads me to the conclusion that the problem is solved if we use `face` in `rainbow-delimiters` instead of `font-lock-face`.
And here I do not know the full consequences. But, since `rainbow-delimiters` also uses `jit-lock` directly (and not through `font-lock-mode`) we are standing on a shaky floor anyway.

Note, that I had already some contact with `rainbow-delimiters` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800243/highlight-first-mismatching-paren/20022030#20022030) but not with `rainbow-blocks`. Because I have only a limited frame of time I chose to concentrate on `rainbow-delimiters`. Maybe, you can solve the `rainbow-blocks`-problem in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's lone instances of '<' and '>' that mess up rainbow-delimiters.

I fixed it with hooking the following to LaTeX-mode (and org-mode, since I use latex there too)

```
(defun my-fix-syntax-entries ()
  (modify-syntax-entry ?< "w")
  (modify-syntax-entry ?> "w"))
```

Regarding '(]'-style intervals, there's a latex package for that which will avoid the problem. Have a look here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326237/how-to-properly-typeset-math-intervals